# finding local max, min, saddle point values when you have different number of solutions for x and y

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I was trying to do this problem here, but after getting fx and fy, I couldn't solve for x in terms of y or y in terms of x, and fx had solutions 0,1,-1, while fy had solutions 1,-1. so what are my critical points then? all my other examples i've seen like this had clear solvable solutions for x and y but I don't know what to do when i have 3 x's and 2 y's. If someone could explain this part fully that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y):=x^4-2x^2+y^3-3y$ then
$$(1)\qquad f_x(x,y)=4x^3-4x=4x(x^2-1)=4x(x-1)(x+1)\\(2)\qquad f_y(x,y)=3y^2-3=3(y^2-1)=3(y-1)(y+1)$$
The critical points occur when **both** $f_x$ and $f_y$ are zero. Thus, the critical points are $(0,1),(0,-1),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)$.

Comment: oh i see its like every combination of the zeros for both equations

Comment: Yes. The critical points are zeros of both $f_x$ and $f_y$. In this example, $f_x$ is only dependent on $x$, and $f_y$ only on $y$, so we are able to get the $x$ value as the root of $f_x$, and the $y$ value as the root of $f_y$. However, it may not be like this in general.